# Why can't a higher kinded trait bound of From<> on an associated type be satisfied, but Into<> can?

Tags: rust

```rust
trait A<'self_> {
    type T;
}

trait B: for<'self_> A<'self_> {
    type U: for<'self_> From<<Self as A<'self_>>::T>;  // <-- this won't compile
    // type U: for<'self_> Into<<Self as A<'self_>>::T>;  // <-- but this will
}

struct M;
impl<'self_> A<'self_> for M {
    type T = usize;
}
impl B for M {
    type U = usize;
}

fn main() {}
```

[playpen link](http://is.gd/xSYneN)

Why will the line marked "this won't compile" fail to compile (even though `From<T>` is implemented for all `T`), while the one marked "but this will" (which depends on a blanket impl on `Into` from `From` in the standard library) will?

I suspect that this is legitimately a bug, but would rather avoid filing anything and adding to the noise if there's simply something special about `From` vs. `Into` I wasn't aware of.